# Check a web page and send an email when a change is detected

Tags: automation, scraping

I have a need to be able to automate the following:

1. Submit a webform (login)
2. Check the next page for given text (it’s a date)
3. Send an email (if date has changed)

I have found a few page watches but I have not found any yet that have the ability to login and then assert a string on a page.

Any ideas?

Comment: As you used the [tag:web-apps] tag, you are only looking for web apps? Hosted and/or self-hosted?

Comment: I dont mind if its web or machine based, app or script, hosted or self hosted, I am flexable

Comment: Okay. If it’s a local solution, does the OS matter? Price?

Comment: prefurably linux or OSX. Open source if possible, if not then 50USD or less.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with [python](http://python.org) and [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to fill in & submit the form, possibly plus possibly [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the resulting 2nd page.  You can then use the supplied [stmplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#module-smtplib) to create and send the required email on a change of the important items from what you stored in the previous run.

- Free, most Linux machines will already have python installed
- Flexible, e.g. you can look at changes in specific items on the results page
- If necessary you can go through several pages to get to the one you are "watching" for changes, e.g. log in, fill in a form, submit then check the quote details for changes from the last time.

Comment: No need to use the heavy Scrapy if you just need to parse the page. Use BeautifulSoup instead which only provides HTML parsing.

Comment: Thanks @AndréDaniel - I have added BeautifulSoup into the answer as it is a good option.